# Grep data from a zipped file Unix

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file having data pipe separated , i want to get a grep a text between 2 times . Below is the file structure

```
2017-04-23 06:43:00|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|
2017-04-23 06:43:01|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|
2017-04-23 06:43:02|1|2|3|4|5|A|
2017-04-23 06:44:00|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|
```

Now i want to count occurrence  of TEST between `06:43:00` to `06:44:00`.I tired using grep

```
zgrep -a "06:43:00" filename.gz | grep "TEST" | wc -l
```

But i am unable to get the count between the 2 times mentioned .

Comment: can't you just zgrep 06:43 filename.gz | grep TEST | wc -l

Comment: but i want the data from 06:43 to 06:44

Comment: including 06:44:00?

Comment: how about egrep '06:43|06:44:00' file1 | grep TEST | wc -l

Comment: i tried but this is not working

Comment: zegrep '06:43|06:44:00' file1.gz | grep TEST | wc -l works for me on cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expression grep (egrep) to grep for more than one pattern

```
zegrep '06:43|06:44:00' filename.gz | grep TEST | wc -l
```

or

```
zcat filename.gz | egrep '06:43|06:44:00' | grep TEST | wc -l

$ zcat file1.gz | egrep '06:43|06:44:00' | grep TEST
2017-04-23 06:43:00|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|
2017-04-23 06:43:01|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|
2017-04-23 06:44:00|1|2|3|4|5|TEST|

$ zcat file1.gz | egrep '06:43|06:44:00' | grep TEST | wc -l
3
```

Or very hacky :

```
  zcat file1.gz | perl -ne 'if(/06:43:00/){$p=1;}if($p){print $_;}if(/06:44:00/){$p=0;}' | grep TEST | wc -l    3
```

Comment: it will match 06:43|06:44 but i want range from 06:43:00 to 6:43:00 . I want all the values between these 2 time

Comment: unless I have missed something it's doing what you want!!

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat filename.gz \
    | awk '/06:43/,/06:44/ { print }' - \
    | grep TEST | wc -l
```

awk usually uses `/<pattern>/ { <action> }`, but it is also possible to define a range with two comma separated patterns.
`/<start-pattern>/,/<end-pattern/ { <action> }`